# Using a virtual keyboard and jQuery to trigger keypresses for a flash game

Tags: jquery, flash, keypress

Is there a way to simulate a key press for a flash game via a virtual keyboard?

Right now I have a "virtual keyboard" which is just 1 button. When I click it, I want it to trigger the pressing of up arrow. But the event needs to be triggered in a flash game.
Here's the button:

```
<button id="sim-up-arrow">Up</button>
```

Here is the flash game:

```
<object id="game" data="a4_truck_parking.swf"></object>
```

And here the jQuery/JS stuff:

```
$('#sim-up-arrow').on('click', function(){
    // create a new keypress event
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 38});
    // focus the game
    $('#game').focus();
    // trigger the up arrow key press
    $('#game').trigger(e);
});
```

Sadly my little truck isn't accelerating.

Comment: does your flash game already reacts to up arrow pressing?

Comment: @Cherniv When I load the page it doesn't. I have to click the slash object first. That's why I tried the focussing

Comment: After a little investigation, it seems you need in the actionscript code Export a function that trigger the keyboard event, and call it from Javascript. It seems imposible to do this with random Flash Games. You need access to their code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the variable "which" to your event, maybe the flash game is reading this field.

```
$('#sim-up-arrow').on('click', function() {
    var e = jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 38, which:38});
    // focus the game
    $('#game').focus();
    // trigger the up arrow key press
    $('#game').trigger(e);
}
```